# C++ Error with getline. How do avoid this error? "no instance of overloaded function "getline"

Tags: c++, getline

I am trying to make a text file that contains usernames and passwords. I want to check if a username has already been taken by comparing the input string to each line in the text file. I am using getline but i am receiving this error message   "no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void RegisterUsername() {

string username0;
string username1;
string user;
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("Data.txt", ios::app);

cout << "Please enter your username:\n";
cin >> username0;
cout << "Please reenter your username:\n";
cin >> username1;
if (username0 == username1) {
    myfile.open("Data.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open) {
        while (getline(myfile, user)) {
            if (username0 == user) {
                cout << "Username is taken. Please try again.";
                RegisterUsername();
            }
        }
    }

    myfile << username0 << "\n";
}
else {
    cout << "Usernames did not match. Please try again.\n";
    RegisterUsername();
};
myfile.close();
};



int main()
{   
RegisterUsername();
RegisterPassword();

cin.get();
};
```

Comment: `if (myfile.is_open)` should be `if (myfile.is_open())`

Comment: and change `ofstream` to `ifstream`, you can't read from an output stream.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-constructing them and immediately overwriting the default values. That is, change `ofstream my file; myfile.open("Data.txt", ios::app);` to `ofstream my file("Data.txt", ios::app);`. Plus, it's a bit odd to open the file back there and then open it again inside the loop. Just create it where you need it. And, finally, you don't need to call `myfile.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: There's another problem with this code. Each time the function gets called it opens the file "Data.txt". If the user names don't match, the function calls itself recursively, which means that it's going to try to open the same file another time. It's generally not a good idea to deal with bad input by a recursive call. Write a loop instead.

Comment: You do get credit for quoting the error message, but I suspect your quote is incomplete. Typically, this sort of error message will additionally specify which types were seen in the parameter list, often followed by a list of candidate overloads. This is intended to allow you see which parameter is the wrong type with much less guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

[getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) function needs an istream and a string, actually you are using a `ofstream` to open the file, but with this you can't read anything from the file because is open only as output.

You could use a ifstream inside this if

```cpp
if (username0 == username1) {
    ifstream read_myfile ("Data.txt");

    if (read_myfile.is_open) {
        while (getline(read_myfile, user)) {
            if (username0 == user) {
                cout << "Username is taken. Please try again.";
                RegisterUsername();
            }
        }
    }

    read_myfile.close();

    myfile.open("Data.txt");

    myfile << username0 << "\n";
}
```